# Filtering a list containing date Strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, date, filter

Below is an example list where each element has a name (for example `XXX`) and associated date(for example `20200115`)

```
[XXX_20200115, XXX_20200116, YYY_20200116, ZZZ_20200116, ZZZ_20200117]
```

I want to remove all the elements from the list which have same name but an old date. For example, I want to remove `XXX_20200115` because `XXX_20200116` already exists with latest date.

so my final output should be :

```
[ XXX_20200116, YYY_20200116, ZZZ_20200117]
```

Till now I wrote this code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def list_duplicates(seq):
    tally = defaultdict(list)
    for i,item in enumerate(seq):
        tally[item].append(i)
    return ((key,locs) for key,locs in tally.items() 
                            if len(locs)>1)


def filterModules(mylist):
    names = []
    timestamps =  []

    for module in mylist:
         splittedName = module.rsplit('_', 1)
         names.append(splittedName[0])
         timestamps.append(splittedName[1])

    duplicates = []
    for dup in sorted(list_duplicates(names)):
        duplicate = {}
        duplicate['name'] = dup[0]
        duplicate['indexs'] = dup[1]
        duplicates.append(duplicate)
```

which gives me duplicates with their indexes.

My issue is, I was aiming to write a minimum code for this problem but my code is getting bigger and seems like I am approaching this problem in inefficient way. Can someone tell me more optimum way of solving this problem and with minimal code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First grouping the elements based on the first 3 letters and from the sub list take `max()`. If it is string also python will take max based on integers:

```
from itertools import groupby

l1 = ["XXX_20200115", "XXX_20200116", "YYY_20200116", "ZZZ_20200116", "ZZZ_20200117"]

l2 = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(l1, key=lambda x: x.split("_")[0])]

new_l = [max(i) for i in l2]

print(new_l)
```

Comment: Even though I love this approach, I think limiting the name to just first 3 letters can be a bad assumption. I believe there must be a way to generalise this.

Comment: How can i modify this code when name can have a variable length? For example, elements can be "XXX_20200115"  or  "YYYYYYYYY_20200116".

Comment: If you are sure that the name and date are seperated by an identifier ,in this case "underscore".
You can split by "underscore" and use first element.

Comment: @VikasP, Can you please explain how max() function is able to give the element with latest date?Is it reliable to use this function?

Comment: @Anudocs in your case date string is in the format of YYYYMMDD format and we can consider this as a whole integer value. And python will take max based on integer values.

Comment: well ok. I was surprised to see that max function can work on strings like 'XXX_20200116' which also has characters other than integers.

Answer (score 0):

I tried utilizing dictionary for this where `XXX`, `YYY` etc can be keys and values can be dates. This is how implementation will look.

```
dt = ['XXX_20200115', 'XXX_20200116', 'YYY_20200116', 'ZZZ_20200116', 'ZZZ_20200117'] 

dt = [tuple(i.split('_'))for i in dt]

new_dt = {}

for i,j in dt:
    if i not in new_dt.keys():
        new_dt[i]=j
    else:
        if j>new_dt[i]:
            new_dt[i]=j

print(new_dt)
```

Which will give

```
{'XXX': '20200116', 'YYY': '20200116', 'ZZZ': '20200117'}
```

Finally if you want to convert to original format when you can just append key and value and make it an array with

```
new_dt = ["{}_{}".format(i,new_dt[i]) for i in new_dt]
```

This will give

```
['XXX_20200116', 'YYY_20200116', 'ZZZ_20200117']
```